# How to align Items at the top and on the bottom in a Sidebar with flexbox?

Tags: html, css, flexbox, sidebar

I basically want to have a Sidebar that looks like the SideBar in Visual Studio Code. There you have Buttons on top and also 2 Buttons at the bottom. I made a Sidebar but I am only capable of positioning all Items at the top OR the Bottom of the Sidebar, but I want both.
I want that 3 Items are on the Top and 2 Items are on the bottom.

Here is my CSS:

```css
.sidebarleft {
  background-color: rgb(25, 20, 26);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}

.sidebarleft-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: rgb(100, 110, 122);
}
```

In my html I have something like this.

```html
<div class="sidebarleft">
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">A</button>
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">B</button>
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">C</button>

  <button class="sidebarleft-button">Y</button> <-- this Item should be on the bottom -->
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">Z</button> <-- this Item should be on the bottom -->
</div>
```

I somehow have to tell my Items how they need to be aligned but I am not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get what you want, apply `margin-top: auto;` to the first element that should be part of the "bottom-group", and leave the `justify-content` setting of the flex container at its default (i.e. no definition for that setting). Also, you need to define a height for the flex container, otherwise it will only have the added *height* of all its children by default (I made it 100vh, i.e. full viewport height, but adjust that as needed):

(note: view the snippet in full page view, otherwise it's not high enough to show the desired result)

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
.sidebarleft {
  background-color: rgb(25, 20, 26);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.sidebarleft-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: rgb(100, 110, 122);
}
.sidebarleft-button:nth-child(4) {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebarleft">
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">A</button>
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">B</button>
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">C</button>

  <button class="sidebarleft-button">Y</button>
  <!-- this Item should be on the bottom -->
  <button class="sidebarleft-button">Z</button>
  <!-- this Item should be on the bottom -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The align-items property is related to CSS layout. It effects how elements are aligned both in Flexbox and Grid layouts.

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

In your case:

```
.sidebarleft {
  background-color: rgb(25, 20, 26);
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
}
```

source:
https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/a/align-items/

Comment: But how can I tell that the 3 buttons stay on top and the other 2 buttons stay at the bottom? This is not possible with your posted approach,.

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple answer you can play around to learn using flexbox.

You can play [This Game](https://flexboxfroggy.com/) for enhance your informations.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.sidebarleft {
  background-color: rgb(25, 20, 26);
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex: 0 0 50px;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 50px;
  padding-right: 50px;
}

.sidebarleft-button {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 15px;
  border: none;
  background-color: inherit;
  color: rgb(100, 110, 122);
}
```

```html
<div class="sidebarleft">
  <div class="sidebar-upper">
    <button class="sidebarleft-button">A</button>
    <button class="sidebarleft-button">B</button>
    <button class="sidebarleft-button">C</button>
  </div>

  <div class="sidebar-bottom">
    <button class="sidebarleft-button">Y</button>
    <button class="sidebarleft-button">Z</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but you did not define `sidebar-upper` and `sidebar-bottom`